# Automate Ivr call by providing dtmf input programatically

Tags: java, ivr, dtmf

I am planning to automate the telephone balance enquiry system. I am planning to build an App that takes card details from user and automatically dial in to a telephone balance enquiry system get the balance and update the balance every day. Can any one please help me to solve this problem  . Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

check out http://www.voxeo.com/. I think you can use it..

Comment: Updated link is [Aspect Prophecy](https://www.aspect.com/in/free)

Answer (score 0):

If you could write this in .NET (C# is VERY similar to Java), use Velocity from Glorsoft. Velocity is Winner of Best Development Tool at IT Expo 2011.

.NET will allow you to integrate easily with other systems e.g. databases, web services.

It can definitely do what you want.

There are some posts on Stack Overflow from some of our customers - take a look.

Disclaimer: I work for Glorsoft.

Answer (score 0):

As Raveesh pointed out Voxeo's Prophecy is a good solution for this. You can get a developer version for free to try this out.  I wanted to add some additional information on how this would work.  You will need to dial out to the other IVR which will require using CCXML.  Voxeo has some good examples on their website on how to use CCXML for outbound dialing.  Once the IVR on the other end answers the phone the CCXML will pass control to a VoiceXML application.  You will need to program this VoiceXML to playback audio files that represent the telephone keypad input (DTMF) a user would perform, or if it is speech recognition the voice input it is expecting.  You can find pre-recorded audio file for DTMF on Voxeo's website as well.  Your may have to program in some delays (recorded silence) in your VoiceXML application to make the audio files play when the other IVR expects them.  This will be required if the balance inquiry system does not support bargein, which allows users to bypass listening to prompts and provide input right away.